# PouchDB replication fails after a while with error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to replicate a remote CouchDB database with PouchDB. Here is the replication call

```
try {
        await PouchDB.replicate(sourceDB, targetDB);
        console.log(`Replication complete!`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Replication failed with error ${err}`);
        throw err;
    }
```

The database (`sourceDB`) is quite large (around 8.2k docs and 28k deleted docs, for a total of 16.6MB).

When calling the above, the replication always fails after around 10.4MB of data have been copied to `targetDB`.

The exception says:

> Replication failed with error {"name":"Error","message":"invalid json
> response body at http://my-db-url/_bulk_docs reason: Unexpected token
> < in JSON at position 0"}

I am using PouchDB 7.2.2 and CouchDB 3.1.0

Comment: With little information to work with, I recommend hooking into all the [replication](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) event emitters (particularly the 'change' event) to generate a log which you may analyze.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"` indicates that the data coming back from the server some time over the process is not in JSON format but probably containing HTML (starting with a tag like `<html>`).

This may be happening if you server is somehow getting overloaded during sync and sends back an error as an html page.

Try opening the [Network tab of the Developer Console](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) and look at the requests, finding the one that fails. Checking its body can give you more information about what is actually happening.